# What causes Redisson Error MapCacheEvictionTask?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redis

I'm working on java spring application where I use RedissonRegionFactory as hibernate second level cache provide, I'm using this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
    <artifactId>redisson-hibernate-52</artifactId>
    <version>3.17.7</version>
</dependency>
```

However running the project causes this error:

```
org.redisson.client.RedisResponseTimeoutException: Redis server response timeout (3000 ms) occured after 0 retry attempts, is non-idempotent command: false Check connection with Redis node: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379 for TCP packet drops.  Try to increase nettyThreads and/or timeout settings. Command: (EVAL), params: [if redis.call('setnx', KEYS[6], ARGV[4]) == 0 then return -1;end;redis.call('expire', KEYS[6], ARGV[3]); local expiredKeys1 = redis.call('zrangebyscore', KEYS[2], 0, ARGV[1], 'limit', 0, ARGV[2]); for i, key in ipairs(expiredKeys1) do local v = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], key); if v ~= false then local t, val = struct.unpack('dLc0', v); local msg = struct.pack('Lc0Lc0', string.len(key), key, string.len(val), val); local listeners = redis.call('publish', KEYS[4], msg); if (listeners == 0) then break;end; end;end;for i=1, #expiredKeys1, 5000 do redis.call('zrem', KEYS[5], unpack(expiredKeys1, i, math.min(i+4999, table.getn(expiredKeys1)))); redis.call('zrem', KEYS[3], unpack(expiredKeys1, i, math.min(i+4999, table.getn(expiredKeys1)))); redis.call('zrem', KEYS[2], unpack(expiredKeys1, i, math.min(i+4999, table.getn(expiredKeys1)))); redis.call('hdel', KEYS[1], unpack(expiredKeys1, i, math.min(i+4999, table.getn(expiredKeys1)))); end; local expiredKeys2 = redis.call('zrangebyscore', KEYS[...]
```

I tried to increase the timeout for my client to 30000 ,by configuring my client in this way

```
final Config redissonConfig = new Config();
 redissonConfig.useSingleServer()
            .setKeepAlive(true)
            .setConnectTimeout(30000 )
            .setRetryAttempts(5)
            .setDnsMonitoringInterval(300)
            .setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
    return Redisson.create(redissonConfig);
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your Redis server is not configured correctly, or is not running. Try checking the Redis server logs to see if there are any error messages.